# Alfresco programmatically navigate to correct folder

Tags: c#, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

I have a question regarding Alfresco and dotCMIS library. Basically i would like to get to a particular folder and create there a document.

At this time i have the following code (i know it is messy, but it was for testing):

```
 Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
            parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://webadress:2005/alfresco/service/cmis";
            parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "amdin";
            parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "admpsw";

            SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
            IList<DotCMIS.Client.IRepository> repositories = factory.GetRepositories(parameters);
            DotCMIS.Client.ISession session = repositories[0].CreateSession();

            foreach (ICmisObject cmisObject in rootFolder.GetChildren())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cmisObject.Name);
                if (cmisObject.Name.Equals("AlfresCO"))
                {
                    var type = cmisObject.GetType();
                    IFolder circabcfolder = cmisObject as IFolder;
                    foreach (ICmisObject obj in circabcfolder.GetChildren())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
                        if (obj.Name.Equals("SubFolder1"))
                        {
                            IFolder circabcfolder2 = obj as IFolder;
                            foreach (ICmisObject obj2 in circabcfolder2.GetChildren())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(obj2.Name);

                                foreach (ICmisObject obj3 in (obj2 as IFolder).GetChildren())
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(obj3.Name);
                                    if (obj3.Name.Equals("Library"))
                                    {
                                        foreach (ICmisObject obj4 in (obj3 as IFolder).GetChildren())
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(obj4.Name);
                                            if (obj4.Name.Equals("MyFolder"))
                                            {
                                                IDictionary<string, object> properties2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                                                properties2[PropertyIds.ObjectTypeId]= "cmis:folder";
                                                properties2[PropertyIds.Name] = "Test Folder";

                                                IFolder newFolder = (obj4 as IFolder).CreateFolder(properties2);

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It just opens a root folder, this means i'm in 'alfresco' for example, then i have to navigate to another sub folder and then another one, and then finally i get to:
/Library, /Groups, /Newsgroups ... etc.
And in Library i can open "My Folder", but is there a more easier way to just open /Library/MyFolder instead of really going through all the layers getting the right folder ...?

Can i do something like .. `session.GetFolderByName("MyFolder")`

I can't also rely on ID, as for example in other portal the ID that is randomly generated for a folder can be different, so i cannot say GetFolderById(..);

So any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with the DotCMISClient, but if you look at the total services (which should be available through the client) then you'll see 2 services which will do the trick

1. [GetObjectByPath](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#Object_Services)
2. [Query](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language#cmis%3afolder)

The query is quite easy where type is cmis:folder and name is "MyFolder".